# JavaScript functions calls (in switch)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-callback

I try to make a code for creating a HTML code, but i stuck here.

```
function generateText(elements, type) {
  for (var i = 0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    alert(elements[i]);
    switch (elements[i]) {
        case "p":
            alert("here p");
            var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
            var link = "text/" + type + "/p/" + num + ".html";
            $.get(link, function(data) {
                setText(data);
                alert("setting p");
            });
        break;

        case "h1":
        alert("here h1");
            var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
            var link = "text/" + type + "/h1/" + num + ".html";
            $.get(link, function(data) {
                setText(data);
                alert("setting h1");
            });
        break;

    }
  }
}
```

Problem is, that if `elements` array is for example [p h1 p h1 p p], i can get data in another order, like [h1 h1 p p p p] or [p p h1 h1 p p] (it makes function `setText()`).

I thought, that functions called so:

`generateText() -> switch -> case "p" -> case "h1" -> case "p" ... !!!-> $.get() 'in p' -> $.get() 'in h1' -> $.get() 'in p' ...!!!`

but i want to have something like this:

`generateText() -> switch -> case "p" -> $.get() 'in p' -> case "h1" -> $.get() 'in h1' -> case "p" -> $.get() 'in p'... !!!`

Hope you will help! 
Thanks all!)

Comment: you want to remove the breaks or what?

Comment: Could you create a Js fiddle for this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.get()` is asynchronous. It means that while the for loop and the switch does go through the elements in the correct order, they only initiate the AJAX call. The callback function (which includes the `setText()` call) is called when the response is received from the server. Because calls to the server might take different amounts of time, it's not guaranteed that they return in the same order they're called.

One solution could be to create empty elements outside the callback and only set the contents when the AJAX call is finished. Without knowing what `setText()` does, the idea is something like this:

```
        var link = "text/" + type + "/p/" + num + ".html";
        var elem = document.createElement( 'p' );
        document.body.appendChild( elem );  
            // elements are now in the DOM in the correct order

        $.get(link, function(data) {
            elem.innerHTML = data;  // set the contents when AJAX call finishes
        });
```

Side note: it's best to use [the console](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) instead of `alert()` for debugging, for variety of reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I have founded another solution: thanks for #Juhana. Ajax call can be sync:

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: 'GET',
    url: link,
    success: function(data) {
         //callback
    }
});
```

but thanks for help!